# What is O'Reilly Curve?

Tags: .net, programming-languages

Can you explain what exactly O'Reilly Curve (defined by Doug Kaye)?

Comment: Can you link to the definition? My google fu fails me at the moment.

Comment: @Oded: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/HTML5-Today screencast; around 15th minute.

Comment: See http://www.codeodor.com/index.cfm/2007/8/13/What-web-framework-should-I-usebrAbout-choices-and-how-they-are-made/1543 (and search inside for "The O'Reilly Curve")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://www.codeodor.com/index.cfm/2007/8/13/What-web-framework-should-I-usebrAbout-choices-and-how-they-are-made/1543):

> Basically, the idea is that "publication of an O'Reilly book signals a transition of that technology from 'innovation' to 'early adopter' phase.